# How to send the nested hashmap from servlet to jquery Ajax to parse the output in jquery

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, servlets

What is the best practice to send the data from servlet to jquery ajax.
I have a java servlet which returns a nested hashmap, how can I pass this data to ajax and further parse this nested hashmap in the jquery/Ajax.

Do I need to convert the nested hashmap to json in my servlet class before sending it to the jquery/Ajax? Is this the only way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I would prefer JSON format for this use-case. Primary reason for doing so is out of box support for JSON in your javascript. You can also explore other data formats like Thrift if the data is big. You can basically send the binary formatted data (Thirft binary) to lower the data transfer latency by reducing the payload size

Comment: JSON is definitely the way to go, try using a Serialization library as https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: I used Jackson and converted to Json for parsing. Thanks! everyone